# How to use square brackets for citations within parentheses using csquotes?

Tags: citing, csquotes

I'm writing an APA style manuscript using the csquotes package for citations. I would like to use square brackets [] to enclose citations that are already within parentheses.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

Previous studies have investigated the influence of spatial features on navigation in real life settings (e.g., on urban \parencite{desyllas_axial_2001} and building \parencite{haq_just_2003} levels).
```

This, however, yields nested parentheses. How can I change the appearance of the parentheses within the parentheses (i.e., change them to square brackets)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to tex.se. `\mkbibparens` does nesting. Is that what you mean?

Comment: For semantic consistency, though, I would keep the () nesting (it's something I would expect - not changing what the eye has become used to seeing in prior text: cognitive load in visual perception, and all that (Cicada 2020)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An experiment using `\mkbibparens` - seems to work with APA-style:

[image: nesting brackets]

(I don't have your bib, so just used a dummy entry.)

MWE

```
    \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @misc{john-73,
        author = {John, S.},
        year = {1973},
        title = {The best book ever},
    }
    \end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

    \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Previous studies have investigated the influence of spatial features on navigation in real life settings (e.g., on building \parencite{john-73} levels).

\mkbibparens{text \mkbibparens{test}}


Previous studies have investigated the influence of spatial features on navigation in real life settings \mkbibparens{e.g., on building \parencite{john-73} levels}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! That does exactly what I wanted.